# Set processOptions for doc ai ocr api request

Tags: apex, cloud-document-ai

We are recommended to activate a flag on our OCR processor for better results because we face some problems (like "I" parsed as "1". To test the flag I want to use Postman, but adding the options to my requests results in an error.
My Request:

```
{

 "skipHumanReview": true,
 "processOptions": {
    ...
  },

  "rawDocument": {
    "mimeType": "application/pdf",
    "content": "..."
  },

  "fieldMask": "text,pages.blocks,pages.paragraphs,pages.formFields"

}
```

Without the processOptions part, the requests works fine. ProcessOptions is not recognized. The Result is:

{
...
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "processOptions": Cannot find field."
...
}

The processor version used is pretrained-ocr-v1.2-2022-11-10
I don't know if I have a wrong version (the one used is the newest I see) or if my request is wrong (I didn't find an example with this flag).
In our application we don't use the provided packages, but build the requests with custom code (APEX), so I will have the same problem using that.

Update:
I found some examples and I am sure, that my request is correct. Then I guess it has to be the version, but pretrained-ocr-v1.2-2022-11-10 is the newset one I get offered
[image]

Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [`ProcessOptions`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/ProcessOptions) can only be specified when using the `v1beta3` endpoint. `https://documentai.googleapis.com/v1beta3`

This documentation shows how to add the field to the [`processRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors.processorVersions/process)

This Python sample shows how to add some options to `ocr_config` the official samples will be updated to include this field once the options are added to the `v1` endpoint.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/document-ai-samples/tree/main/pdf-embedded-text

Previous Answers about this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76211040/6216983
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366063/6216983
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75859053/6216983